# How to implement file search by pattern?

Tags: linux, pattern-matching

I need to get the file name and assign this name to the variable. The file has the following format: `webapp-1.1.2.jar`. Versions are constantly changing. How to get file name using pattern in linux console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regex which will match any pattern where the version numbers vary for the jar file.

```
webapp-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.jar
```